# Pass by pointer not updating memory address

Tags: c++

I am wanting to read back data stored in a buffer. I have a function that takes a pointer to an unsigned char array as a parameter. I wanted this parameter to be populated (point to) the address of the buffer I wish to obtain.

Inside the function I can see while debugging that the parameter passed in is being updated correctly (Mock class), however once I return from this function to the calling method (Connection class), all the data is lost.

Please can anyone help me understand why this is?

Thanks in Advance

### Unit Test

/// Unit test fails as expected data is not in the buffer

```
TEST(MemoryTest, TestWriteAndRead)
{
        Connection* p_conneciton = new Connection();

        /// Write
        uint8_t txBuffer[_USB_PACKET_SIZE] = _CMD;
        ASSERT_EQ(p_memory->Write(txBuffer), true);

        /// Read
        uint8_t* rxBuffer;

        ASSERT_EQ(p_memory->Read((unsigned char*)&rxBuffer), true);

        ASSERT_EQ(rxBuffer[0], 0xaa);
    }
```

### Connection Class

```
/// Information is lost here in _pu8_buffer
bool Connection::Read(uint8_t* _pu8_buffer)
{
    int i_bytesRead = 0;
    while(i_bytesRead != SIZE) {
        i_bytesRead = read_timeout(_pu8_buffer, _PACKET_SIZE);
        if ( i_bytesRead < _PACKET_SIZE) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

### Mock Class

```
/// Information is copied correctly here from mpuc_data to data
int Mock:read_timeout(unsigned char* data, size_t length)
{
    if (data == nullptr) {
        return -1;
    }
    data = mpuc_data;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you want to change the pointer inside the function (and not just the value it points to) you have to pass the pointer via reference (eg. a pointer to a pointer)

Comment: `(unsigned char*)&rxBuffer` This seems wrong. Yout won't need such a strange casting to get new pointer to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass by reference parameters you want to modify. If you want to modify the value of a pointer, it's the *pointer* you need to pass by reference -that it is a reference itself (to something else) won't help.

Try

```
int Mock:read_timeout(unsigned char*& data, size_t length)
{
    if (data == nullptr) {
        return -1;
    }
    data = mpuc_data;

    return 0;
}
```

this way, `_pu8_buffer` will actually point the same as `mpuc_data` after each call to `read_timeout`. You can do the same with the function `Read`.

In general, pay attention to levels of indirection. With

```
uint8_t* rxBuffer;

ASSERT_EQ(p_memory->Read((unsigned char*)&rxBuffer), true);
```

you're taking the address of a `uint8_t*`, obtaining a `uint8_t**`, pointer to a pointer. Then you cast it to `unsigned char*` -a simple, not double pointer! (and then implicitly to `uint8_t*` when it becomes a parameter) It can't end well... and it ends in trying to read an array of chars where the first 4 or 8 are in fact the bytes of your pointer, followed by other garbage.

Taking the address of a pointer is correct if you want to modify it, but then you need to expect a `uint8_t**` on the other side, and refer to it as `*_pu8_buffer`.

Comment: Thank you for that explaination, extremely helpful and clearly defined :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/// Information is lost here in _pu8_buffer
bool Connection::Read(uint8_t* _pu8_buffer)
{
    int i_bytesRead = 0;
    while(i_bytesRead != SIZE) {
        i_bytesRead = read_timeout(_pu8_buffer, _PACKET_SIZE);
        if ( i_bytesRead < _PACKET_SIZE) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Calling this function gets you a copy of the pointer you passed to it. Meaning that if you change the location that the pointer is pointing to you only change the local copy.

You either change the way you set the data in `read_timeout` to:

```
*data = mpuc_data;
```

Or you pass a pointer to a pointer (`uint8_t**`) in `Connection::Read` and call `read_timeout(&_pu8_buffer, _PACKET_SIZE);`

Also, the way you currently have it `&rxBuffer` is not correct, it should be `rxBuffer`. Only pass the address if you change the signature to a `uint8_t**`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer very much appreciated! :)